# Failed to authenticate HTTPS connection using Visual Studio 2019 for Mac and React-Native Android emulator

Tags: c#, android, reactjs, react-native, .net-core

I've created a .net core 2.2 WebAPI project using Visual Studio 2019 for Mac. I have a React Web App as well as a React-Native app. I've been trying to allow the Android emulator to connect to the local debug version but all I get is the following error:
[20:50:36 DBG] Failed to authenticate HTTPS connection.
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception. ---> Interop+AppleCrypto+SslException: unknown certificate

I'm using Android Studio emulator to run the React-Native app. I have the calls going to https://10.0.2.2/ and it's hitting the server without a problem. I have ran `dotnet dev-certs --clean` and `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` and it doesn't help at all.

All of the fixes that I've seen so far are either to run the two dotnet commands or to add C# code to turn off the ssl check. Since this is a react-native project, there's no place to put the c# code and I have no idea how to do that in react-native and have been unable to locate anything online.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Previously, my workaround was to have a remote server that I would just constantly push changes to in order to test the mobile side, but it's getting to be a huge pain to keep doing that.